# Background Listview in select, hover - Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Good morning ... I'm creating a program in Delphi, but I'm very accustomed to programming for web (HTML, CSS, PHP, JS) ... For WEB is very easy customize any TAG ...

```
select {background: #ABEAFF; color: #CCC;}
```

But now for Delphi, I'm having a lot of trouble to customize a Listview ... Well, I can add the background:

```
TForm4.OnCustomDrawItem procedure (Sender: TCustomListView; Item: TListItem;
   State: TCustomDrawState; var DefaultDraw: Boolean);
var
   Color: TColor;
begin

     if (Trim (Item.SubItems.Strings [0]) = Trim (Item.SubItems.Strings [1])) then Begin
       Color: = RGB (205, 255, 206);
     End else Begin
       Color: = RGB (253, 172, 172);
     end;
     ListaItensHeader.Canvas.Brush.Color: = Color;
  // End;
     memo1.Text: = item.SubItems.Strings [1];
end;
```

But it there is a HOVER effect and SELECT (FOCUS do not know) ... How to change the background color in these cases?

Comment: `cdsHot in State` signals that the item is *hot-tracked*, `cdsSelected in State` that it's selected.

Comment: Assuming VCL, you are looking for VCL styles. Thankfully MS locks down thee themeing to achieve consistency across the desktop. Apps that want to do theoir own thing are possible with, e.g. VCL styles but you'll end up with an app that looks like 1997 WinAmp.